# What is the middle-ware platform for developing windows phone applications?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, middleware

I am double minded of what to say is middle-ware platform between .NET and Windows Phone?. Because i believe even the operating system itself is a platform. What I do not know is can it also be refereed to as a middle-ware.
Help me understand what the mobile middle-ware platform for developing windows phone applications is?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to develop windows phone application you need visual studio any edition 2015 recommended.
respective sdk for respective phone i.e - for windows phone 8 and 8.1 you need windows phone8.1 sdk and and for windows 10 you need to install windows universal sdk

you can go through this links [1](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) ,  [2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk)

install all comment if more help require.